# What was the first version of Python that included SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite

- What was the first version of Python that included SQLite?
- What version of SQLite was included?

I thought Python 2.5 was the first version to include SQLite, but I was hoping someone could confirm that and the version of SQLite that was first included.

Comment: Although some linux distributions can break Python in more than one package - so it is possible to have a python a post 2.5 isntall without the sqlite functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have noted, a snapshot of the `pysqlite2` was merged into the Python standard library and released as the `sqlite3` module in Python 2.5.  There has been subsequent independent development on `pysqlite2` which has been merged back into `sqlite3` at various points for subsequent Python releases and `sqlite3` has received its own bug fixes.

There is no one correct answer to the question of which version of `SQLite` was included because the Python source code distribution does not include the source for `SQLite`.  The build process, for Unix-style builds, depends on an externally provided copy of the library.  It is up to each distributor of Python to decide how to manage that.  For instance, the current python.org installer 32-bit-only variants for Mac OS X statically includes a version of the SQLite library while the 64-bit variant for 10.6 dynamically links to the system-supplied version of the library.  So, to answer your second question, you would need to check each distribution of Python 2.5 and determine what version(s) of SQLite each was statically or dynamically linked with.

Answer (score 8):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html):

> 11.13. sqlite3 — DB-API 2.0 interface for SQLite databases
>
> **New in version 2.5.**

Answer (score 5):

It was first included in python version **2.5**.

The version of sqlite was **3.0.8**, based off of the **pysqlite2.1.3** library.

Found here: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5/NEWS.txt (search for "sql").

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5/NEWS.txt), Version 2.5 alpha 1